# how to authenticate and authorize at each route level in angular 4 with keycloak

Tags: angular, session, authentication, authorization, keycloak

I have integrated Keycloak with our application.Login and Logout flow is working properly except one scenario.I wanted to authenticate then authorize each route. Because when user clears the browser session or clear session from admin console of keycloak, when user tries to access other route it says 401 since I have written AppGuard. I have tried to check getKeycloakInstance() it returns same object when has valid session and after session expires also. Then I tried to call init(config) from canActive() of AuthGuard it was looping continuously. How to authenticate at route level.

### app-routing.module.ts

```
{
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AppAuthGuard],
    data: {
            path:'/idam/*'
    },
    loadChildren: './idam/idam.module#IdamModule'
},
```

### app-auth-guard.ts

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    if (!this.keycloakService.getIsClientSecretKeyFetch()) {
      this.errorHandler._enlivenErrorhandler.handleError({"status":"401","message" :"Unable to get client details. Please contact your administrator ","url":window.location.href});
      this.router.navigate(['404'], { queryParams: { tenantId: this.cookieService.get('tenantId') } });
    }
    return super.canActivate(route, state);
  }

  isAccessAllowed(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      if (!this.authenticated) {
        this.keycloakAngular.login();
        return;
      }

      const path = route.data.path;
      this.keycloakService.isAuthorized(path).then(
        (res) => {
          let access = res;
          if (access) {
            resolve(true);
          } else {
            resolve(false);
          }
        });
      resolve(true);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Auth Guard if the session already exists we can verify the token by sending a request to Keycloak Protected resource with token in header..If the response is 401 we can redirect the route to the login page.
I have done it like this

url:

```
http://Keycloakurl/auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Avinash Kumar. I was looking for solution at UI level. I realized that needs to make an API call as you told. Thanks for your Answer